# Wordpress Shorcode Display hierarchical taxonomy [child, parent]

Tags: shortcode, taxonomy

I have a slight problem to display the parents of taxonomy in wordpress.
**(CPT=property and tax = property_city)**

I did a little research to figure out what to do.

but I can't quite figure out how to display them.

I will give you an illustration, you will quickly understand.

[image]

**what I have (not actual shortcode or any code! Just dynamic tag term showing taxonomy without parent)**

[image]

**what I want to do**

[image]

the ideal will be to display them in shortcode, so I add them where I need.

I tested this method but it obviously does not work..

I think I still did not understand something..

```
function taxonomy_hierarchy() {
    global $post;
    $taxonomy = 'property_city'; //Put your custom taxonomy term here
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
    foreach ( $terms as $term )
        {
    if ($term->parent == 0) // this gets the parent of the current post taxonomy
    {$myparent = $term;}
        }
    echo ''.$myparent->name.'';
    // Right, the parent is set, now let's get the children
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ($term->parent != 0) // this ignores the parent of the current post taxonomy
        { 
        $child_term = $term; // this gets the children of the current post taxonomy
        echo ''.$child_term->name.'';
        }
    }   
}

add_shortcode( 'child-parent', function () {

    $content = "echo ''.$child_term->name.'' echo ''.$myparent->name.''";

    return $content;
} );
```

code found here : [link](https://cambodesign.com/wordpress-how-to-get-taxonomy-hierarchy-on-a-single-post/)

**UPDATE 04/01/2021**

millions thank to Stef
I did the tests on my loop and single post it works well.

```
function taxonomy_hierarchy() {
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$return = '';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'property_city' ); //Put your custom taxonomy term here
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    // this gets the parent of the current post taxonomy
    
    
     //attempt to make terms clickable
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
    
    if ($term->parent != 0) {
        $return .= $term->name. ', ' . get_term( $term->parent, 'property_city' )->name;
    } else {
        $return .= $term->name;
    }
}
return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'city-area', 'taxonomy_hierarchy' );
```

and finally understood how to do shortcodes and the logic behind it.
as i try to understand the logic behind the php, I forgot to mention to make the terms **clickable** [get_term_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) I should be able to **enable and disable** them (parent or child or both) with "//" (optionnal)
**How to do that ?**

I already have this piece of code which redirects them to my custom request (inside elementor builder for exemple ) since shortcode is not clickable it does not work on them..

```
add_filter ('term_link', function ($ termlink, $ term, $ taxonomy) {
// taxonomy city
if ('property_city' == $ taxonomy) {
         $ termlink = trailingslashit (get_home_url ()). 'property /?_city ='. $ term-> slug;
     }
     return $ termlink;
}, 10, 3);
```

After a little thought, what if someday i need something like this ...

[image]

[image]
how to make it **flexible** and display the available terms **hierarchically**?
I think this 
[WordPress: Get taxonomy hierarchy, including children](https://www.daggerhartlab.com/wordpress-get-taxonomy-hierarchy-including-children/)
 has a link with my question?

but I can't put the puzzle together

thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `taxonomy_hierarchy()` is not actually linked to the shortcode. Your function `taxonomy_hierarchy()` is also not a proper shortcode function.
You can find how to create proper shortcodes [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/).

A shortcode function also has to *return*, don't use *echo*.

This is how your function `taxonomy_hierarchy` should *kinda* look. I changed the code for your needs:

```
function taxonomy_hierarchy() {

global $post;

$return = '';

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'property_city' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    // this gets the parent of the current post taxonomy
    if ( $term->parent != 0 ) {

        $return .= $term->name ', ' . get_term( $term->parent, 'property_city' )->name;

    } else {

        $return .= $term->name;

    }

}

return $return;

}
```

Then add this to create the shortcode from the function `taxonomy_hierarchy()`.

```
add_shortcode( 'child-parent', 'taxonomy_hierarchy' );
```

When using the shortcode frontend, you can then use `[child-parent]`. Backend you can use `echo do_shortcode( '[child-parent]' );`

Comment: millions thanks

I updated my post see my answer .

you seem to know php well,
I think maybe you should take a look at my posts I have been stuck on some details for a while.